# Change an exact word on exact roll in ASCII file

Tags: sed, grep, xargs

I need to change a string from a file, which repeats on every row, but I need to change it only for couple of rows (not for all rows).
Lets say, the /etc/fstab file:

```
/dev/mapper/rhel-root            /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-boot            /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-home            /home                   ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-var             /var                    ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/workvg-swaplv        swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

How can I change the "defaults" string to "string" only for /home and /var entries?
the thinks I've tried are using a lot of combinations of grep|sed|exargs etc., but it doesn't work as expected :)

```
echo $(egrep "/var | /home" fstab | awk '{ print $4}') | xargs -I '{}' sed 's/{}/string/' fstab
```

Can someone gives me some idea regarding this?
Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -E '/\/(home|var)/ s/defaults/string/' fstab
/dev/mapper/rhel-root            /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-boot            /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-home            /home                   ext3    string        1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-var             /var                    ext3    string        1 2
/dev/mapper/workvg-swaplv        swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

- `-E` use extended regex
- `/\/(home|var)/` this is to match only those lines with `/home` or `/var`
- `s/defaults/string/` substitute required pattern with replacement string

**Edit:**

For more robust matching:

```
sed -E '/^\S+\s+\/(home|var)\b/ s/^((\S+\s+){3})defaults\b/\1string/' fstab
```

This checks for exact match of `/home` or `/var` in 2nd column and replaces exact match of `defaults` in 4th column

`\b` checks for word boundary, `\s` matches whitespace, `\S` matches other than whitespace

Comment: While this will produce the expected output given the posted sample input, there's a LOT of ways it would fail with other input, e.g. if rhel-boot was home-boot or if string contains & or if mapper was defaults or .... so - just be careful when using it!

Answer (score 1):

This will work robustly for all input lines and for all values of `defaults` and `string` that do not contain backslashes (an easy tweak if you do have those):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { split(entries,t); for (i in t) tgts["/"t[i]] }
($2 in tgts) && match($0,/^((\S+\s+){3})(\S+)(\s.*)$/,a) && (a[3]==old) { $0 = a[1] new a[4] }
{ print }

$ awk -v entries="home var" -v old="defaults" -v new="string" -f tst.awk file
/dev/mapper/rhel-root            /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-boot            /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-home            /home                   ext3    string        1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-var             /var                    ext3    string        1 2
/dev/mapper/workvg-swaplv        swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

It uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), other awks would use substr().

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/\/var/ || /\/home {sub(/defaults/, "string")} 1'` /etc/fstab
```

- `/\/var || /\/home` if keywords in the record
- `sub{/defaults/, "string")` replace first "defaults" with "string"
- `1` print changed and unchanged records

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/home|var/{sub(/defaults/,"string  ")}1' file

/dev/mapper/rhel-root            /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rhel-boot            /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-home            /home                   ext3    string          1 2
/dev/mapper/rhel-var             /var                    ext3    string          1 2
/dev/mapper/workvg-swaplv        swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```